# Nginx match for favicon related files

Tags: nginx

Favicons have become more and more unruly. To cater for all browsers/platforms I am using [this excellent service](https://realfavicongenerator.net/). What I get is the following files:

```
android-chrome-192x192.png  favicon-16x16.png  mstile-150x150.png
android-chrome-512x512.png  favicon-32x32.png  safari-pinned-tab.svg
apple-touch-icon.png        favicon.ico
browserconfig.xml           manifest.json
```

The recommended path for these is the web root as some browsers do not honor custom paths. I *really don't want* to have such a mess in my web root. So, I am looking for a `location` configuration to place them all in their dedicated directory while letting the clients think they are in the web root.

I have seen *exact match* rules like this:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
  root /var/www/path/to/favicons;
}
```

But 10 exact match locations just for these files is not a very good solution. What else can I do?

Comment: 10 exact matches is good solution. Just put them in separate file and `include` it

Comment: @AlexeyTen I would still prefer not to resort to using this. Let's see if an alternative is proposed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this - it's a case insensitive regular expression match for anything containing the substring favicon, plus tests for most of the other expressions. I've put in two exact matches because there's a chance the URLs could be used in an application. If "favicon" is used in the application it will cause problems.

```
 # Better option below for this line
 location ~* favicon|apple-touch-icon|android-chrome-|mstile-|safari-pinned-tab.svg|browserconfig.xml {
  root /var/www/path/to/favicons;
}
location = /browserconfig.xml {
  root /var/www/path/to/favicons;
}
location = /manifest.json {
  root /var/www/path/to/favicons;
}
```

I've run a quick test and this seems to work.

[Tero Kilkanen](https://serverfault.com/users/210570/tero-kilkanen) offers this location, which would be a better match. It matches starting at the root directory only and has a non-capturing group.

```
location ~* ^/(?:favicon|apple-touch-icon|android-chrome-|mstile-|safari-pinned-tab.svg|browserconfig.xml|manifest.json)
```

However, I would probably just put all the location block matches into a file and include it. I assume exact matches are a touch faster, and my Nginx config files can get up to 500 lines anyway.

Comment: I did a quick test and it seems to work ok.

Comment: By including, do you mean to have a separate config file linked to in sites-enabled? If not, how would one *include* a file in a config?

Comment: Using the [Nginx Include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive. I have an nginx.conf that includes a separate file for each website I host. Each file has four server blocks, to account for the http/https and www/non-www domains. Those servers include other files as required, such as one that sets security headers like STS. If you only have one server that serves content just put this into that file.

Comment: SInce favicons are supposed to be located in web root directory, I would refine the regex such that it only matches files in the root directory.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen that sounds like a good idea. Do you just stick a slash in front of each section? My regex skills are fairly basic.

Comment: `location ^/(?:favicon|apple-touch-icon|android-chrome-|mstile-|safari-pinned-tab.svg|browserconfig.xml)$` would be a more refined one, with start and end anchors and then a non-capturing group with alternate matching strings.

Comment: Thanks Tero, I'll move that into my answer, with credit.

Comment: I can only get @TeroKilkanen's version to work with an added ~* to indicate use a regexp rather than just prefix `location ~* ^/(?:favicon|apple-touch-icon|android-chrome-|mstile-|safari-pinned-tab.svg|browserconfig.xml|mainfest.json)` I also had to drop the trailing $ to allow favicon-16x16.png to work.

Comment: @Mat You are definitely right, my answer missed the `~` for the regex matching.

Comment: @Tim : Looks like there is a spelling mistake...should be manifest.json.  Also many people use site.webmanifest ....no big deal but figured I would mention it.

Comment: @hendr1x I would update for errors but I don't really understand what you're saying. Manifest appears to be spelled correctly. Generally I wouldn't update a six year old answer with additional information, fix a problem yes, but additional info not really.

Comment: @Tim : Please review again.  The error was copy/pasted from Tero.  It is currently spelled mainfest

Comment: @hendr1x Oh I see, another one that was off to the right, I had to scroll to see it. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

I see many errors in my logfile, for clients try to access :

`https://my.server.com/some/location/document.html/apple-touch-icon.png`

so why not to give them what they want ?

here the config that works for that :

```
# non capturing group is ok here, but a $ at the end would be simply wrong
# this is deliberately not limited to the root directory, because 
# clients look at all places for especially for apple-touch-icon
#
# so we match here : 
#    https://my.server.com/apple-touch-icon*,
#    https://my.server.com/*...*/apple-touch-icon*
# and rewrite to /var/www/path/to/favicons/apple-touch-icon*
#
# on the rewrite we NEED a capturing group !

location ~* /(?:favicon|apple-touch-icon|android-chrome-|mstile-|safari-pinned-tab.svg) {
      rewrite ^.*/(favicon|apple-touch-icon|android-chrome-|mstile-|safari-pinned-tab.svg)(.*)$  /$1$2 break; 
      root /var/www/path/to/favicons;
    }

    # this should be only found in the root
    location = /browserconfig.xml {
      root /var/www/path/to/favicons;
    }

    # this should be only found in the root
    location = /manifest.json {
      root /var/www/path/to/favicons;
    }
```